# How do I execute either an <include /> or a <merge /> programmatically?

Tags: android, merge, include

I am generating a display from an input script. The top and bottom sections are repeatable - as in a merge or include file - except for one minor text change which can be handled easily by a 'setText()' instruction. The middle section is dictated by the script and can be of variable length and content. The generated view is then added as a child view to a ScrollView.

Currently, I have a script string which describes both the top and bottom sections and a 'marker' in the middle which is replaced by the variable 'middle section' script provided by a user database. This structure I believe could be more efficiently expressed and generated if I could incorporate a 'merge' or 'include' facility in the script. This implies that I would have to be able to implement the merge or include function in Java code.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Q: Can't you read your script as a file resource at runtime?  And, if so, wouldn't that solve the "include" question?

Comment: At the Java coding level, couldn't you put any static string values in any class or interface you want, and simply "include" them from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is part of a code I used to generate a `LinearLayout` full of a repeating `LinearLayout` in a recent project. It functions the same way as `<include />`, by inflating a layout XML file.

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(/* Your context here */);
ViewGroup layoutTarget = /* Some layout object */;

// ...

for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
    // ...

    final View v = li.inflate(R.layout.name_of_your_layout, layoutTarget, false);
    layoutTarget.addView(v);
}
```

You should be able to adapt this to your need. The key here is calling the `.inflate()` method, which creates a new instance of that layout.

Comment: Thanks, Soxxeh. Looks good. I'll confirm this in the next day or so.